# OWASP Dependency-check does not scan any issue with Jenkins pipeline but freestyle job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, maven-dependency-check-plugin

I am running OWASP dependency-check in Jenkins. However, when i run it with Jenkins freestyle job, it shows 2 vulnerabilities from the report. But with the same source code, i run it with Jenkin pipeline, it shows the report, but 0 vulnerabilities.

Here is my Jenkinsfile:

```
            stage ('Dependency Check') {
            steps {
                dependencyCheck additionalArguments: ''' 
                    -o "./" 
                    -s "./"
                    -f "ALL" 
                    --prettyPrint''', odcInstallation: 'dependencycheck'
                dependencyCheckPublisher pattern: 'dependency-check-report.xml'
            }
        }
```

Thank you in advance.